# Installing heroku with Ruby on Rails stucks... (Windows 10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, railsinstaller

I am using Windows 10 and have installed Ruby on Rails and all the other components with rails installer while actually following the instructions here:

http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_a_heroku_account

While after installing toolbelt and trying to connect to heroku through the "heroku login" command the computer is basically... stuck...

This is how it looks:

```
C:\Sites>heroku login
heroku-cli: Installing Toolbelt v4... done
For more information on Toolbelt v4: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli
heroku-cli: Adding dependencies... 12 MB/12 MB
heroku-cli: Adding dependencies... 4.34 MB/4.34 MB
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...
```

What am I supposed to do now? (For the record I have tried uninstalling the toolbelt and after restarting the computer I have tried everything again).

Would it be better for me, under the circumstances to try and use APTANA and connect heroku through it?

Comment: The heroku staff is usually pretty good about helping people. I'd shoot their support staff a message. They deal with this stuff day in and out, so they will likely know a solution. If you find it, post back here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029991/heroku-comannd-always-fails/33043592#33043592

Comment: thank you for your advise.

i have solved to provelem by removing and reinstalling the the bundler.

i have no Iead whay to prolem is solved since i am really new to coding at this stage but any way... that solved it.

thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your advise.

i have solved to provelem by removing and reinstalling the the bundler.

i have no Iead whay to prolem is solved since i am really new  to coding at this stage but any way... that solved it.

thanks again.